# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space with JSON conversion

Tags: java, json

```
listaDecretoSingolo = new ArrayList<>();
listaDettaglioDecretoSingolo = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 1022; i++){
    decretoSingoloTemp = new DecretoSingoloViewObject("Roma", "ABCDE3593CXXE",
    "decreto singolo", date,new BigDecimal(56000), new BigDecimal(343434),
    new BigDecimal(55656), new BigDecimal(9999));

    for(int j = 0; j < 111; j++){
        listaDettaglioDecretoSingolo.add(new DettaglioDecretoSingoloViewObject(22,
                                date, "numero dec pag",
                                "tipo pag", new BigDecimal(45),
                                "nota dec"));
                    }
        decretoSingoloTemp.setDetails(listaDettaglioDecretoSingolo);
        listaDecretoSingolo.add(decretoSingoloTemp);
}
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
String jsonList = null;
jsonList = ow.writeValueAsString(listaDecretoSingolo);
```

I want test the speed of this code above. But, when I run it, and it tries to convert the list into a JSON string I get this exception:

```
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.carr(TextBuffer.java:703) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.expand(TextBuffer.java:664) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.TextBuffer.append(TextBuffer.java:455) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.io.SegmentedStringWriter.write(SegmentedStringWriter.java:67) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._flushBuffer(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:1910) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeRawLong(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:496) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeRaw(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:430) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter$Lf2SpacesIndenter.writeIndentation(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:472) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.util.DefaultPrettyPrinter.beforeObjectEntries(DefaultPrettyPrinter.java:265) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writePPFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:297) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator._writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:227) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json.WriterBasedJsonGenerator.writeFieldName(WriterBasedJsonGenerator.java:116) [jackson-core-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:539) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanPropertyWriter.serializeAsField(BeanPropertyWriter.java:541) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields(BeanSerializerBase.java:644) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializer.serialize(BeanSerializer.java:152) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:100) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.impl.IndexedListSerializer.serializeContents(IndexedListSerializer.java:21) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.AsArraySerializerBase.serialize(AsArraySerializerBase.java:183) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:114) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter._configAndWriteValue(ObjectWriter.java:809) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter.writeValueAsString(ObjectWriter.java:684) [jackson-databind-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
at it.istruzione.hp.scuoleSicure.controller.ConsultaPagamentiController.ricercaConsultaImpegni(ConsultaPagamentiController.java:116) [classes:]
at it.istruzione.hp.scuoleSicure.controller.ConsultaPagamentiController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$8a5debc0.invoke(<generated>) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:708) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.0.5.RELEASE.jar:4.0.5.RELEASE]
```

I don't get this error when the list has a small size (like 10, 20, 30..). But, when I increase the size, near thousands or little less, I have this problem...

There is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a lot of objects, so you need a lot of memory. Try using the -Xmx option to increase maximum heap size.

[Xmx and Xms are well explained here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14763079)

Comment: And when I publish the war on the server that's not mine (like the client server)?

Answer (score 1):

Try to write json as [ObjectWritter#writeValueAsBytes](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#writeValueAsBytes%28java.lang.Object%29) or [ObjectWritter#writeValue(OutputStream out,Object value)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.5/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectWriter.html#writeValue%28java.io.OutputStream,%20java.lang.Object%29)

Writing as String is highly ineffective

Something like this:

Bar.java

```
package org.ibm.jackson.example;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

    public class Bar {
        private String id;

        @JsonCreator
        public Bar(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Bar [id=" + id + "]";
        }

    }
```

JacksonMain.java

```
package org.ibm.jackson.example;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectWriter;

public class JacksonMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException  {

        String json = "{\"id\": \"foo\"}";
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        final Bar bar = mapper.readValue(json, Bar.class);
        //Read json
        System.out.println(bar);

        ObjectWriter objectWriter = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        byte[] barWritten = objectWriter.writeValueAsBytes(bar);
        //Written json
        System.out.println(new String(barWritten));  //Just to show - you should write something like ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(barWritten);

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean that I should convert the list in byte array before, and then from byte array to JSON?